# Number Format with Thousands Separator and Decimal if Necessary

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a custom format such that the number will be displayed with commas as the thousands separator. Where I am struggling to find a solution (both through trial and error as well as searching) *with a decimal point if* the number has one, but *without a decimal point* if the number is whole.

Here's what I would like to achieve:
- "123" displays as "123"
- "1234" displays as "1,234"
- "1234.5" displays as "1,234.5"
- "1234.56" displays as "1,234.56"
- "1234.567" displays as "1,234.57"

Here's what I have tried so far, to no avail:

```
Print Format(1234, "Standard") 'Displays "1,234.00"
Print Format(1234, "#,###.##") 'Displays "1,234."
```

These are not the desired results, as it unnecessarily displays the decimal. How can I access the decimal point when needed, and avoid when not, all while having the thousands separator?

Comment: @KSSheon Format spec you've mentioned ( "#,##0.00") will display trailing zeros and decimal point even in integer numbers: it's not what PO is asking for. The right solution is given below. Best regards,

Comment: yes you are right. :)

Comment: @KSSheon It's OK :-) Rgds,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may complete this task by using the custom format Function `CustomFormat` in Excel VBA as shown below:

```
Sub TestFormatString()
    Debug.Print CustomFormat(123)
    Debug.Print CustomFormat(1234)
    Debug.Print CustomFormat(1234.5)
    Debug.Print CustomFormat(1234.56)
    Debug.Print CustomFormat(1234.567)
End Sub

Function CustomFormat(InputValue As Double) As String
    CustomFormat = Format(InputValue, "#,###.##")
    If (Right(CustomFormat, 1) = ".") Then
        CustomFormat = Left(CustomFormat, Len(CustomFormat) - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

The result shown below conforms to your requirements:

```
123
1,234
1,234.5
1,234.56
1,234.57
```

***Note***: as you didn't specify how to display the numbers less that 1 (for example, 0.123) then consider two possible solutions:

- `CustomFormat` VBA Function shown above will display it as
  .12
- in order to display it as 0.12, just change the format mask from "`#,###.##`" to  "`#,##0.##`" in `CustomFormat` Function, keeping the rest intact.

Hope this may help.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Comment: I could not find this in Excel 2010, nor documentation for `CustomFormat` on MSDN. Can you give me a pointer? thanks.

Comment: @cbaldan Click on the item "Number" on Excel Ribbon Menu, then in the Dropdown list navigate to "Custom" (it resides on the last line).

Comment: @AlexBell thanks a bunch. I read this in a hurry and did not realize the VBA `Function CustomFormat()` was proposed on the code snippet above.

Comment: @cbaldan You are welcome. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3):

You can add **Conditional Formatting** for those with a Decimal then set the default Number Format with 0 decimals.

1. Add **Conditional Formatting**: with `#,##0.##` unless you want `0.5` as `.5`
   [image: ConditionalFormatting]
2. Set **Default Number Format**:
   [image: DefaultNumberFormat]
3. Done
   [image: Results]