# Ultimate 1000 separator using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to get VBA solution for 1000 separator as in my case it is not possible to use formula and should be done with custom code.
Current solution is taken from answer [Number Format with Thousands Separator and Decimal if Necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001900/number-format-with-thousands-separator-and-decimal-if-necessary)

Here is the code:

```
Function CustomFormat(InputValue As Double) As String
    CustomFormat = Format(InputValue, "# ###")
    If (Right(CustomFormat, 1) = ".") Then
        CustomFormat = Left(CustomFormat, Len(CustomFormat) - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

It is working for numbers like 1000, but it does not work for 1000000. Also 1000000000 will not work. I am currently working on solution, but if somebody has something to share, it would be appreciated.

In case of using original solution:

```
Function CustomFormat(InputValue As Double) As String
    CustomFormat = Format(InputValue, "#,###.##")
    If (Right(CustomFormat, 1) = ".") Then
        CustomFormat = Left(CustomFormat, Len(CustomFormat) - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Are the numbers that you are trying to format always integers?

Comment: Why did you change the format string from the previously answered question? That worked correctly for 3/6/9 zeroes.

Comment: I was just trying different solutions and figured out that in my case integer can be used. However I was also thinking of creating something that will suite others as well. In my case there are no `.` or `,`. Only numbers `1234567890`

Comment: @OwlsSleeping in case of `MsgBox CustomFormat(45646545)`, you will get `45 646 545,`. The last character is wrong = not necessary

Comment: If you copied it exactly, the result would be 45,646,545

Comment: @OwlsSleeping I have copied it using CTRL + C, CTRL + V :). I am getting `45 646 545,` as an output

Comment: What you are seeing with the original solution must be due to some locale setting. For integers, using simply `"#,###"` works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think vba needs the thousands separater that is defined in your regional settings. Since it is a comma in your case you can do something like this

```
Function CustomFormat(InputValue As Double) As String
    CustomFormat = Format(InputValue, "#,###")
    If (Right(CustomFormat, 1) = ".") Then
        CustomFormat = Left(CustomFormat, Len(CustomFormat) - 1)
    End If
    CustomFormat = Replace(CustomFormat, ",", " ")
End Function
```

Another approach is to read the separator from the registry. This should work in different regional settings.

```
Function CustomFormat(InputValue As Double) As String
    Dim sThousandsSep As String
    Dim sDecimalSep As String
    Dim sFormat As String
    
    sThousandsSep = Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)
    sDecimalSep = Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)
    
    ' Up to 6 decimal places
    sFormat = "#" & sThousandsSep & "###" & sDecimalSep & "######"
    
    CustomFormat = Format(InputValue, sFormat)
    If (Right$(CustomFormat, 1) = sDecimalSep) Then
        CustomFormat = Left$(CustomFormat, Len(CustomFormat) - 1)
    End If
    
    ' Replace the thousands separator with a space
    ' or any other character
    CustomFormat = Replace(CustomFormat, sThousandsSep, " ")
End Function
```

**Edit** Changed function to use `Application.International` as suggested by @RonRosenfeld.

Comment: FYI. You can also obtain the settings for the thousands and decimal separator in VBA with `Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)` and `Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That's amazing: updated the code. I assume (as well the cleaner code) this saves the overhead of creating an object. It's amazing how much one learns by **answering** questions :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend your number format to include the larger numbers.

#### ### ### ##0","

[image: Custom Number Format Dialog]