# Custom number (price) format independent of localization

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am wondering is it possible to have custom number format using Excel formula that will not be dependent on localization of Excel application (EU/US)?

For example I have value 1291660.

Then using formula `=TEXT(A1;"# ##0,00")`. I get as an output `1 291 660,00`. The target is to have in any case `1.291.660,00` as an output. Any Excel professional to give an advice?

I have tried `=TEXT(A1;"#.##0,00")` - This didn't work

I think VBA is the only solution to this. I have found my old question about the same topic, but it seems that solution provided is not working for some reason?

[Ultimate 1000 separator using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63436786/ultimate-1000-separator-using-vba)

```
Function CustomFormat(InputValue As Double) As String
    Dim sThousandsSep As String
    Dim sDecimalSep As String
    Dim sFormat As String
    
    sThousandsSep = Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)
    sDecimalSep = Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)
    
    ' Up to 6 decimal places
    sFormat = "#" & sThousandsSep & "###" & sDecimalSep & "######"
    
    CustomFormat = Format(InputValue, sFormat)
    If (Right$(CustomFormat, 1) = sDecimalSep) Then
        CustomFormat = Left$(CustomFormat, Len(CustomFormat) - 1)
    End If
    
    ' Replace the thousands separator with a space
    ' or any other character
    CustomFormat = Replace(CustomFormat, sThousandsSep, " ")
End Function
```

By replacing `CustomFormat = Replace(CustomFormat, sThousandsSep, " ")` with `CustomFormat = Replace(CustomFormat, sThousandsSep, ".")` output is `.1 291 660`

Comment: Any reason why you won't use normal custom number formatting?

Comment: I think `,` and `.` can be swapped using regional settings if using windows

Comment: @AnilGoyal that is correct, but I am not able to change all the settings for possible users and check that this setting is applied. It is not only my computer. I would also prefer to perform this change only to certain cells I would like to apply, not the whole system or Workbook.

Comment: see the answer proposed

Comment: @JvdV I would prefer to do it with formula to leave possibility for applying additional conditions later. For example be able to change output price format based on currency selected or other parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FIXED(A1,2,0),",","."),".",",",INT(LEN(A1)/3)+1)
```

---

The way it works is that on an EU-system `FIXED()` will return: `1.291.660,00` but on an US-system it should return `1,291,660.00`. To create the same output-string, we can `SUBSTITUTE()` all comma's to dots. A 2nd `SUBSTITUTE()` will then replace only the last dot back to a comma. To find the right index I used `INT(LEN(A1)/3)+1` which works well on itegers like `1291660`. If you happen to have decimal values, you can change this to:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FIXED(A1,2,0),",","."),".",",",INT(LEN(INT(A1))/3)+1)
```

---

**EDIT:**

The above should always return the desired format, **but** it's a string. To return the numeric value in any further calculations, you can use `NUMBERVALUE()`:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(C1,",",".")
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to excel file tab, click options and then the following options as desired

[image]

Uncheck `use system separators` and define your own

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this. You can use SUBSTITUTE to replace the default separator characters, and you can detect what these are by cutting them out from the formatted string of a known number. I use ASCII 1 (SOH) character to avoid replacing twice (e.g. replacing thousands separator from " " to ".", than replacing decimal separators from "." to "," would cause that thousands separators appear as ","):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(1234567.89,"# ##0.000"),MID(TEXT("# ##0",1000),2,1),CHAR(1)&" "),MID(TEXT("0.0",0.1),2,1),CHAR(1)&","),CHAR(1)&" ","."),CHAR(1)&",",",")
```

This will output "1.234.567,890".

This output will appear as a string (you cannot add numbers to it, and it is left adjusted by default), and you cannot change this behavior if you don't use Excels local settings for separators.

BTW, using " " for thousands separator and either "." or "," for decimals is the clearest way of displaying numbers.

Comment: Thank you! I am testing this currently, in my case it seems like it should be `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(E6;"# ##0,00");MID(TEXT("# ##0";1000);2;1);CHAR(1)&" ");MID(TEXT("0.0";0,1);2;1);CHAR(1)&",");CHAR(1)&" ";".");CHAR(1)&",";",")`

Comment: This solution is working! I have marked other one as an answer just for sack of simplicity. Otherwise this is also well working solution